# Why am I getting an error in Java AS400 error while extracting files?

Tags: java, ibm-midrange

At my job we use this batch file to extract text files from our AS400 and save them on our hard drive. here is a sample of the bat file:

```
    echo on
    
    REM ****************
    SET mydate=%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%-%date:~12,2%
    SET myuser=%username%
    echo %myuser%
    REM ****************
    
    C:
    
    cd C:\Users\%myuser%\IBM\ClientSolutions\Start_Programs\Windows_i386-32\
    
    echo on
    echo Starting AS400 Transfer For Marketing Files as %myuser%
    echo.

    acslaunch_win-32.exe /plugin=download \\Path\DGCC008P.dtfx >> 
    \\Path\TransferLogs\clm_Monthly_%mydate%_Log.txt
```

This was working last month for a user and it still works on my system but it stopped working for this user.  I do not have much java or AS400 experience and tried doing a search online.  Here is the error.  [image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Most likely the user's installation of ACS got changed or moved and their ACSBundle.jar (which contains the AcsResourceManager class that the error message says is Not Found) is no longer where the AcsLaunch_Win-32 program expects it to be.

Answer (score 0):

What you see indicate a situation where some Java classes cannot be found where they are being looked for (the Java class path which is notoriously brittle)

The top part of the screen shot indicate that the "jt400.jar" (which might have another name depending on how you got it) is not on the classpath anymore (as it has worked before).